# How to display the column value descending when the column having spacial characters in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to display the column desc order when the column having spacial chars in mysql
 I am using the follow query but not display correctly

```
SELECT quotation_pno FROM crm_quotation  order by quotation_pno desc
```

My output coming like this

```
 quotation_pno
 PT/17/999
 PT/17/1533
 PT/17/1532
 PT/16/1531
```

I want my output like this

```
 quotation_pno
 PT/17/1533
 PT/17/1532
 PT/17/999
 PT/16/1531
```

Please help me

Comment: did you want descending order based on middle number `PT/17/1533` like `17,16...` is it ?

Comment: Consider normalising your data

Comment: I want both middle and last

Comment: The problem is that he wants the final part '999' treated as if it is '0999' - a simple character-based sort isn't going to do this.  @Strawberry is right

Comment: Yes,that is the problem.Thanks for your valuable time and support.

Comment: is it possible to remove the second slash in column value

Comment: It is posdible to do the ordering, but it is never going to be efficient. Normalisation (splitting up the field) is the key as @Strawberry has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue, that the output *is* correct, but your assumptions are not. It looks to me, as if `quotation_pno` is some kind of textual column, right?

The sorting assumes, that you want to sort *text* and this works this way:

1. Set `i` to 0
2. Compare the `i`-th character of two strigns
3. If they are the same and the end is not reached, increase `i` by 1 and proceed with step 2
4. Otherwise order the two strings according to the value at the `i`-th position

(There are some things elided and the pseudocode is boiled down to the very basic, needed to understand the principle).

Applied to your example this means, when the comparison compares `PT/17/999` and `PT/17/1533` it looks at the characters 0 to 5 and "sees" that they are equal. When it compares the characters at position 6, they are `'9'` and `'1'`. Since the character `'9'` is considered to be greater than `'1'`, `PT/17/999` is placed before `PT/17/1533`.

**How to solve the issue?**

There are some ways coming into my mind, that will allow you to achieve the desired sort order.

First, you could prepend the numbers with zeros. This will allow you to re-use most of your existing structure, but will result either in very many zeros, or a system that is somehow limited, since you will be restricted to the number of digits you decided to use (or the sort will fail again).

The second possibility is, to store the parts in (additional) numerical columns in the table, e.g. one for year and one for the order number in this year. This is the more flexible approach, but involves more changes.